# Ruby 2.1: Forwardable Module and def_delegators

Tags: ruby, oop, composition

I have a question about a refactoring I have done on an example.

Here is the original code:

```
class Parts
  attr_reader :parts

  def initialize(parts)
    @parts = parts
  end

  def size
    parts.size
  end

  def spares
    parts.select{|part| part.needs_spare}
  end
end
```

Here is the refactored code:

```
require 'forwardable'
class Parts
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@parts, :size, :each
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(parts)
    @parts = parts
  end

  def spares
    select{|part| part.needs_spare}
  end
end
```

In the spares method the original code executed "parts.select{|part| part.needs_spare}" and then in the refactoring it was adjusted to "select{|part| part.needs_spare}". How does the new spares method know what instance variable it is selecting from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In the new code, `select` is `self.select`.
- `self.select`, as all methods in `Enumerable`, uses `self.each`.
- `self.each` is forwarded to `@parts.each`

Comment: Interesting. I just removed the .each method to test the Parts class and I got the error "`select': undefined method `each' for #<Parts:0x00000001538530> (NoMethodError)". In this code I was able to remove the :size method and it did not throw an error. Very cool. Thank you for the proper and well explained answer.

Comment: Don't you mean, "all methods in `Enumerable` *that return an enumerator* use `self.each`?  That's most `Enumerable` methods, but there are several that don't return an enumerator (`count`, `drop`, `first`, `grep`, `include?`, `inject`, `max`, `none?`, etc.).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No, I literally mean all methods in `Enumerable`. Try for yourself: `class Foo; include Enumerable; def each; puts "EACH!"; yield 7 end end; Foo.new.count` prints `EACH!` before returning `1`. How do you think `count`, `drop`... know what to count, or drop from, or whatever?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, which produced an "ah, ha" moment.